# Does Corona SDK automatically align apk's when you build for Android?

Tags: adt, coronasdk

I'm just wondering if step 4 is included in Corona's build process, or if you have to do it manually.

https://developer.android.com/tools/help/zipalign.html

[4.] Align the final APK package

Once you have signed the APK with your private key, run zipalign on the file. This tool ensures that all uncompressed data starts with a particular byte alignment, relative to the start of the file. Ensuring alignment at 4-byte boundaries provides a performance optimization when installed on a device. When aligned, the Android system is able to read files with mmap(), even if they contain binary data with alignment restrictions, rather than copying all of the data from the package. The benefit is a reduction in the amount of RAM consumed by the running application.

The zipalign tool is provided with the Android SDK, inside the tools/ directory. To align your signed APK, execute:

$ zipalign -v 4 your_project_name-unaligned.apk your_project_name.apk
The -v flag turns on verbose output (optional). 4 is the byte-alignment (don't use anything other than 4). The first file argument is your signed .apk file (the input) and the second file is the destination .apk file (the output). If you're overriding an existing APK, add the -f flag.

Caution: Your input APK must be signed with your private key before you optimize the package with zipalign. If you sign it after using zipalign, it will undo the alignment.

For more information, read about the zipalign tool.

Comment: You should ask Corona team about this http://www.coronalabs.com/about/contact/

Comment: When I check the alignment using zipalign -c -v <alignment> existing.apk, it looks like it is already aligned. I'll try building an unaligned apk with the ADT, checking the alignment of that, and comparing the results.

Comment: Write it as an asnwer if you will find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that both Corona and ADT build processes do alignment automatically.

The output from zipalign looks the same before and after alignment but I'm not sure what the output means exactly.

They both say "Verification succesful", and have either (OK) or (OK - compressed) after each file.

Also on http://developer.coronalabs.com/demo/2.0BetaGuide.pdf

It says:
"Also, you do not need to use jarsigner 
or zipalign. "

I think that they left this sentence out of their official docs, it looks like it is only in the 2.0 Beta guide.